# Differentiate User and Owner Info in Apps Script Installable Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

When I call `Session.getActiveUser()` from a function called by an installable trigger (e.g. an OnOpen Event trigger in Google Sheets - but not the Simple Trigger) in Apps Script, what user information am I getting?

I understand that installable triggers run under the owner/creator of the trigger regardless of who has opened the sheet. So would this always return that person's info?

Either way, how do I get the information of the other person? (e.g. if it gives owner info, how do I get the info of the user actually opening it - and vice-versa)

**Update:**

I got another user to test my script. I watched the logs while they were in the file, and it definitely reported THEM as the user, even when the installable OnOpen trigger was triggered.

This is good from the perspective that it showed them the correct menu options - he and I saw different menus per my OnOpen script, which is what I want.

However, this raises two issues for me:

1. This seems to go against the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), which states: "Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them. For example, if you create an installable open trigger, it runs when your colleague opens the document (if your colleague has edit access), but it runs as your account. This means that if you create a trigger to send an email when a document is opened, the email is always sent from your account, not necessarily the account that opened the document."
2. In a future function, I will be calling an API from another App. This API will need my credentials (API ID and Secret). I was hoping / expecting that I could "sandbox" my credentials in an installable trigger - invisible to other users - that will allow them to use my credentials just for the specific functions which I would script into the API. If the installable trigger is in fact, NOT using my credentials, then how can I do this? I don't want to have to make every user go to the other App and generate their own set of API credentials, that will be unsustainable in this organization, and not everyone should need to do that.

Comment: As what the answer below suggests, webapp with proper permission would do or belonging to the same organization. Or when onOpen is triggered, ask for the name of the user instead using [prompt dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs) is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

It should return whomever triggered the script. But it depends if the security policy does allow you to access the user's identity. Seeing the documentation:

> Gets information about the current user. **If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, User.getEmail() returns a blank string.** The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user).

I have tested it and even an installable trigger won't return anything if it belongs to a different organization.

But you might be able to if other users belong to the same organization.

> However, these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or belongs to the same Google Workspace domain as the user.

#### Workaround:

- One thing I guess would be to assign the triggered function into a button and have the users click that upon opening the sheet. Via clicking the button, I have been able to show the `User` object using that method.
- Or a webapp that will serve as a relay and will get the `User` details.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this out yet, but all users are in the same organization so it should work. My issue is, since I'm the owner I only see my experience. I can't yet tell what other users will see. I'll need to get someone else to Alpha test it for me and check. Thank you for the response. I'll update after I try it.

Comment: You're welcome @Trashman. If it still doesn't work (which is highly unlikely), easier workaround would be [prompt dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs) during `onOpen` events though is very susceptible to manual errors such as typos.

Comment: I updated my question. I don't have to have them click a button since it gives me their info to begin with. However, now it's not using my info as I expected, so it changes my problem a bit. I do eventually plan on going the WebApp route, but I'm still hoping to make this work in Apps Script until I'm ready to deploy an actual WebApp.